# Can I change vscode color theme programmatically?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does the vscode api allow us to change the currently set color theme ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this works:

```js
let currentTheme = await vscode.workspace.getConfiguration().get("workbench.colorTheme");

await vscode.workspace.getConfiguration().update("workbench.colorTheme", "Red");

let newTheme = await vscode.workspace.getConfiguration().get("workbench.colorTheme");
```

It seems a little funky on testing in the `Extension Development Host` but even though `currentTheme` may be`undefined` when the current theme is not set by `workbench.colorTheme` (as a default themes don't seem to necessarily be) the `update()` still does work.

`vscode.window.activeColorTheme` does not get the active theme name, only whether it is `Dark/Light/HighContrast` and is not settable - but you can see what the user's current preference is with respect to dark/light/high contrast at least.